# How to stimulate press the Windows key using “keyboard.press();

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

I'm trying to stimulate the windows key button using pynput but cant find any answers in the pynput documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try `Key.cmd`:

"A generic command button. On PC platforms, this corresponds to the Super key or Windows key, and on Mac it corresponds to the Command key. This may be a modifier."

[Source](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key.cmd)